# how do I link another library in makefile

Tags: dll, build, makefile, shared-libraries

i have my makefile (not written by me) as follows

```
        SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPENDS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)
LDFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs gtkmm-2.4 gtkglextmm-1.2 lua5.1) -llua5.1
CPPFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-2.4 gtkglextmm-1.2 lua5.1)
CXXFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) -W -Wall -g
CXX = g++
MAIN = game

all: $(MAIN)

depend: $(DEPENDS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Creating $@...
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) 

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $<...
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

%.d: %.cpp
    @echo Building $@...
    @set -e; $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
                  | sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g' > $@; \
                [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@

include $(DEPENDS)
```

now I wanted to link libfmodex.so which is in the current directory, I tried putting it somewhere in the code with -L. libfmodex.so, but gcc says g++: error: libfmodex.so: No such file or directory, but I know it is in the current directory, how exactly do I link that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `LDFLAGS` variable something like: `-L. -lfmodex`

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfmodex

Comment: why is it searching the /usr/bin/ld folder for my .so file instead of my current folder?

Comment: @user961936: That's not what the error means. It means that *the program ld, which is located in /usr/bin,* cannot find the .so file.

Comment: You've marked this question as answered.  Do you still have a problem?  Or not?

Comment: prob solved, with your solution plus export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/library/"